# Ghost: Custom error message

Tags: custom-error-pages, ghost-blog

Is there a way to have custom error message. For example, instead of having `Page Not Found` for 404, we can have `Page Non Trouvé` (in french!).

Is it possible? Directly from the `error.hbs` page?

Or maybe is it a french pack?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can provide your own `error.hbs` file with your template (see: http://support.ghost.org/ghost-themes-overview/#error.hbs). In your custom error page you can show the error message in french or customize it's appearance with handlebars.

Ghost is going to provide better language support in the future. For now it's still on the wishlist (see: http://ideas.ghost.org/forums/285309-wishlist/suggestions/7191893-localization).

Comment: But how can I change the default `Page Not Found` message to another one? I can overwite it, but this is not the best way. I can also put no `{{message}}` tag, and replaced it with my message, but it will not differencies the 404 and 500 page.

Comment: You are right. I thought that it would be possible to use handlebars but that's not the case. Another idea would be to use JavaScript on the frontend to show the correct error message according for `{{code}}`?